# Select Em Duas Tabelas Diferentes - ERRO de trazer todos os atributos em uma tabela só

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: foto das tabelas]

`Já esta trazendo o que eu preciso só que não posso usar o UNION ALL porque os dados ficam em um mesmo atributo (NM_RESIDUO), preciso q fique duas colunas(NM_RESIDUO E QTD_RESIDUO)`

`me ajudem, não sei como faço para trazer os dois`

---

```
SELECT NM_RESIDUO FROM TB_RESIDUO

INNER JOIN TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE ON TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE.ID_TIPO_RESIDUO = TB_RESIDUO.CD_RESIDUO

UNION ALL

SELECT QTD_RESIDUO FROM TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE

INNER JOIN TB_SOLICITACAO ON TB_SOLICITACAO.CD_SOLICITACAO = TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE.ID_SOLICITACAO

INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE ON TB_CLIENTE.CD_CLIENTE = TB_SOLICITACAO.ID_CLIENTE 
 
WHERE TB_CLIENTE.CD_CLIENTE =34;
```

Comment: Forneça detalhes do modelo senão é impossível opinar. Qual a razão do UNION  pois TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE está nos dois SELECTs ?

Comment: Eu usei o union para trazer atributos de tabelas diferentes, mas eu preciso que traga sem juntar os dados em uma tabela só

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: NM_RESIDUO e QTD_RESIDUO vem de qual(is) tabela(s) ? O sql não parece fazer sentido só no 2° se testa o CD_CLIENTE por exemplo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Consegui resolver. Ficou Assim`

SELECT TB_RESIDUO.NM_RESIDUO, TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE.QTD_RESIDUO

FROM TB_RESIDUO

INNER JOIN TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE ON (TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE.ID_TIPO_RESIDUO = TB_RESIDUO.CD_RESIDUO)

INNER JOIN TB_SOLICITACAO ON (TB_SOLICITACAO.CD_SOLICITACAO = TB_RESIDUO_CLIENTE.ID_SOLICITACAO)

INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE ON (TB_CLIENTE.CD_CLIENTE = TB_SOLICITACAO.ID_CLIENTE)

WHERE TB_CLIENTE.CD_CLIENTE =34;

`obrigado gente`